# why must gnu binutils be configured for a spefic target. What's going on underneath

Tags: gcc, binutils

I am messing around with creating my own custom gcc toolchain for an arm Cortex-A5 cpu, and I am trying to dive as deeply as possible into each step. I have deliberately avoided using crosstool-ng or other tools to assist, in order to get a better understanding of what is going on in the process of creating a toolchain.

One thing stumples me though. During configuration and building of binutils, I need to specify a target (--target). This target can be either the classic host-tuple (ex: arm-none-linux-gnuabi) or a specific type, something like i686-elf for example.

Why is this target needed? and what does it specifically do with the generated "as" and "ld" programs built by binutils?

For example, if I build it with arm-none-linux-gnueabi, it looks like the resulting "as" program supports every arm instruction set under the sun (armv4t, armv5, e.t.c.).

Is it simply for saving space in the resulting executable? Or is something more going on?

I would get it, if I configured the binutils for a specific instruction set for example. Build me an assembler that understands armv4t instructions.

---

Looking through the source of binutils and gas specifically, it looks like the host-tuple is selecting some header files located in gas/config/tc*, gas/config/te*. Again, this seems arbitrary, as it is broad categories of systems.

Sorry for the rambling :) I guess my questing can be stated as: Why is binutils not an all-in-one package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this target needed?

Because there are (many) different target architectures.  ARM assembler / code is different from PowerPC is different from x86 etc.  In principle it would have been possible to design one tool for all targets, but that was not the approach taken at te time.

Focus was mainly on speed / performance. The executables are small as of today's 'standards' but combining all > 40 architectures and all tools like `as`, `ld`, `nm` etc. would be / have been quite clunky.

Moreover, not only are modern host machines much more powerful, that also applies to the compiler / assembled programs, sometime zillions of lines of (preprocessed) C++ to compile.  This means the overall build times shifted much more in the direction of compilation that in the old days.

Only different core families are usually switchable / selectable per options.